# Request body replaces the plus sign with spaces

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
 
});
```

When I receive text with plus sign, it gets replaced with space.

For example if my text is:

`a+b`

it gets replaced with

`a b`

How can I solve this issue? I want to receive the text as it is.

Here is my handle submit function on the client side:

```
function handleSubmit(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/', data)
        .then(response =>  {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    }
```

Comment: It needs to be URL-encoded on the client side.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm using react, how can I do that?

Comment: Oh, I mis-read anyway, didn't see it was a post. How are you making the request?

Comment: @DaveNewton Please help